# Edge label above the edge

Tags: jung, jung2

I'am using JUNG2 to visualize my graph. I would like to ask if is there anyway to put edge label above the edge not exactly on it?

Thx in adv.

Answer (score 2):

Found it by mysefl... If anyone needs it just use: vv.getRenderContext().setLabelOffset(20);

Comment: Did you face my problem?
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639303/jung2-network-a-glitch-with-edge-label-offset)